# upper bound on number of components of GMM

Tags: clustering, gaussian-mixture-distribution

I want to fit GMM to a data set with N data points in D dimensions.

I am using the full GMM in MATLAB, i.e., each component has a complete covariance matrix (as opposed to diagonal covaraices which could be shared across components).

Thus, the total number of parameters for a GMM with k components is:

```
(k-1) + k*D + k*(D*(D+1)/2)
```

Is there an acceptable upper bound on the number of components k?

Comment: Depends on how meaningful you want your clustering to be, and how good the numerical precision of your input data is. I'd use at least 100 input points per parameter.

Comment: thanks @Anony-Mousse. That makes sense, is there any literature for this that I could cite?

Comment: @Anony-Mousse do you mean 100 points per parameter of per cluster? If you mean per parameter then that ends up being a huge number, e.g., with D=10 and k=5, it makes 279 parameters which will need 27,900 points which is quite large.

Comment: Yes. But otherwise the statistics are not stable. To even just get a good estimate of the mean you need a large enough sample. The error scales with sqrt(N), so that aren't all that many samples. Not even a million yet.

Comment: Unfortunately in the domain of biology, in which I work, it is not possible to collect such large data sets.

Comment: Then it may be better to use approaches with less parameters to estimate, and make sure to validate any result carefully. E.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_error#Standard_error_of_the_mean gives the *expected* error of the mean. If there is another cluster within this deviation, then they most likely aren't separate clusters (but that is not a very powerful test, and not to be used to prove that clusters are different)